# Advice: Best way to sync sqllite ios to web

Tags: objective-c, ios, sqlite, core-data, synchronization

Just after some advice and recommendations here if I may.

I'm creating an iPad app (IOS6) that will write data to the local database on the device and then either straight away or later on replicate that record to a web service (so a Cloud service basically).

What is the best way to go about this you think?

I was thinking of just having a column in the local DB called "synced" and set the flag to '0' right away when the record is created, then sync records with a '0' either right away or during regular intervals. Then obviously set the flag to '1' when each record is replicated.

I want the app to work offline and then sync when the device has an available connection to my web service.

Ideally every record should be replicated right away or seconds later, but in the event of no network connectivity I want to be able to queue the replication to occur.

So what's the best way or achieving this you think? Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is going to depend a lot on how complex your total solution is.

For example, if the records are only being created on the local device and then uploaded, without ever being modified, then your solution will be more than adequate.

However, if you allow update of the records on the local device or the records can be updated once they get into your web service, then you need to start managing conflict resolution. The way that we address this situation is to record a timestamp in the "master" database (the one updated by the web service) and synchronize that timestamp when a record is uploaded either as a new record or as an update. When the user updates a record, we send the timestamp and if the value in the database is different than the sent database, the update request is rejected. Of course there are different approaches to this conflict resolution, this is just one that works for our application and users.

Comment: The local records will never change once they've been written. So sounds like i'm on the right path then.

Comment: Yes, definitely. No need to get complex if they are write-once.